# JRI and R - not able to capture output

Tags: java, r, plot, jri

I am trying to plot some graphs using Java and R (JRI and Rengine). When I write something like this in my code it works fine:

```
re.eval("plot(c(1,5,3,8,5), type='l', col=2)");
```

But if I write this:

```
re.eval("source(\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\abc\\My Documents\\Test Data\\BoxPlot.r\");");
```

the output window flashes for a moment and vanishes. This specified file contains only 1 command, as the first one, i.e. `re.eval("plot(c(1,5,3,8,5), type='l', col=2)");`

I am very new to R, so this may be a very basic question. But I am not able to find it out. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

**I am using Windows XP.**

Here is the full code:

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class JavaGDExample1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rengine re;
    String[] dummyArgs = new String[1];
    dummyArgs[0] = "--vanilla";
    re = new Rengine(dummyArgs, false, null);
    re.eval("library(JavaGD)");

    // This is the critical line: Here, we tell R that the JavaGD() device that
    // it is supposed to draw to is implemented in the class MyJavaGD. If it were
    // in a package (say, my.package), this should be set to
    // my/package/MyJavaGD1.
    re.eval("Sys.putenv('JAVAGD_CLASS_NAME'='MyJavaGD1')");

    re.eval("JavaGD()");
//    re.eval("plot(c(1,5,3,8,5), type='l', col=2)");
    re.eval("source(\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\abc\\My Documents\\Test Data\\BoxPlot.r\");");
//    re.eval("source(\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\abc\\My Documents\\Test Data\\testPlot.r\")");
    re.end();
  }
}


import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.rosuda.javaGD.GDCanvas;
import org.rosuda.javaGD.GDInterface;

/**
 * This is a minimal reimplementation of the GDInterface. When the device is opened, 
 * it just creates a new JFrame, adds a new GDCanvas to it (R will plot to this GDCanvas)
 * and tells the program to exit when it is closed.   
 */
public class MyJavaGD1 extends GDInterface {
  public JFrame f;

  public void gdOpen(double w, double h) {
    f = new JFrame("JavaGD");
    c = new GDCanvas(w, h);
    f.add((GDCanvas) c);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setTitle("Naked R plot");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You path is wrong - you're entering the quoting hell, what you sent to R is

```
 source("C:\Documents and Settings\abc\My Documents\Test Data\BoxPlot.r");
```

which is invalid:

```
 > source("C:\Documents and Settings\abc\My Documents\Test Data\BoxPlot.r");
 Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "C:\D"
```

To avoid the quoting hell, it is safer to assign file names:

```
 re.assign("fn", "c:\\foo\\bar");
 re.eval("source(fn)");
```

or use `/` instead of `\\`

PS: use stats-rosuda-devel for rJava/JRI questions

Comment: I had to modify the `    re.eval("source(\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\abc\\My Documents\\Test Data\\BoxPlot.r\");");` as `    re.eval("source(\"C:\\\\Documents and Settings\\\\bchitte\\\\My Documents\\\\Vistakon\\\\Test Data\\\\testPlot.r\")");`

Comment: Basically I add to add 4 `\` instead of 2. Your answer gave me proper direction. Thanks.

Comment: But it still leaves me with 1 new question. If the initial path itself was wrong how does R show the window which disappears in a flash?

Comment: The window comes from the `JavaGD()` call that you evaluated directly.

Answer (score 0):

`re.eval("Sys.putenv('JAVAGD_CLASS_NAME'='MyJavaGD1')");`

should be now

`re.eval("Sys.Sys.setenv('JAVAGD_CLASS_NAME'='MyJavaGD1')");`

Sys.setenv() is a new (and preferred) synonym for Sys.putenv() and is now deprecated in favour of Sys.setenv().

[source](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/2.6.0/NEWS.R-2.6.0)